# Terminology: multivariable when multiple levels of categorical variable?

Tags: multiple-regression, categorical-data, terminology, multivariate-regression

Oftentimes, one sees people use terms such as univariate and multivariate logistic regression, where they clearly refer to number of predictors rather than number of response variables. I know it might be better to use term multivariable instead of multivariate in such circumstances. My question is, when there is a categorical predictor with several levels, would it be considered univariable (univariate) or multivariable (multivariate) model within this context? The confusion arises from the notion, that despite there being one predictor, it formally corresponds to several dummy variables, where, for example, each dummy variable would be associated with respective odds ratio.

Comment: FWIW, "multivariate" regression usually refers to multiple *response* (dependent) variables, while "multiple" regression refers to more than one explanatory variable.  As far as your question goes, why would it be important to call your situation "single" or "multiple"?  That would give us a clue concerning how to answer.

Comment: For example, I read a paper when they claim to have analysed some associations using univariate logistic regression, when there is some qualitative factor with more levels (for example, ethnicity). It is not clear, if they mean that they used each level as separate model (which is equivalent to one overall model without intercept). In some fields it is custom to first do logistic regression with individual predictors, which people refer to as "univariate' and than take significant predictors within one 'multivariate'model'

Comment: I know that terminology they use is not optimal, but it is what it is

Comment: Why do you have to choose? One simple but also serious answer is don't use terminology you think is confusing or might confuse. I dislike terms like "univariate logistic regression" and would if was needed call that "single predictor logistic regression", but naturally I can't reach into literature to edit out terms I don't like. As you say, terminology is what people use, and what they should use can be quite a different matter.

Comment: I am asking not because I want to use this terminology, but I want to understand what people refer to when using it.

Comment: Who are "they"?  It's likely different communities of researchers employ the same English words in different ways.  Thus, without that information, it's unlikely we could provide definitive answers. As a general proposition, you can answer your question by researching the publications and references within whatever group of publications you are reading.